# JSON query parameter in API Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, api-gateway

I would like to send a request that contains a query parameter like `?key={"a" : "b"}` through AWS API Gateway. 
Url parameters are encoded but API Gateway but response is always a 400 status code. 
What needs to be done in order to forward the request to the backend?

Comment: The URL parameters are encoded *how*, exactly?  URL-encoding is a standard that is unfortunately not sufficiently precise, so what are the actual bytes being sent by the client? Are you using any mapping templates, or just passthrough to an HTTP service on the back-end?  Anything in the logs?  I would suggest that we'll need some additional details or an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: URL parameters are encoded since are sent by a front-end library (i.e. jQuery). To reproduce the error just send a query parameter like the one described `?key={"a" : "b"}` to an API Gateway endpoint that uses a Lambda as backend and you'll see that the backend is never called